# How to get a dynamic array input from use in php

Tags: php

I want to get an input like 2 testcase and the the values 32 43 ,if three testcases

2
32
43

3
54
43
56

how can this be done with html and php.

I get stuck with the looping according to the number of tescses the user gives..

i have a java version of my code ..

```
// get the number of testcases
System.out.println("Enter the number of test cases");
number = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());



  // loops in as many time the testcase is specified ans stores in array
  for(int n=1 ;n<number;n++,i++)
     {
          System.out.println("enter the N and K value for testcase:"+n);
          myArray[i] = Integer.parseInt(in.readLine());

     }
```

Comment: Is it `PHP` you using?

Comment: yes i want to do the same coding in php but i don no how...

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the input field is `testcase` and values are insert blankspace separated and the form is submitted via `POST` method, then you can get the array by -

```
$testcases = explode(' ', $_POST['testcase']);
```

Comment: works fine now... but i get this error in browser 
Notice: Undefined index: testcases in C:\Apache24\htdocs\index.php on line 23

Comment: Are you using any `if else` block? Try to use that variable with in its scope.